# Disable button depending on user

Tags: xpages

I have a simple xPage with a button. I want to disable the button whenever the user is not the user "X". How can I do that? I tried to make Computed value for the "Disabled" field and failed all the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your attempt to compute the disabled property look like?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I tried to compare the "session.getEffectiveUserName()" ( I have a field that shows what user is currently logged in) with that field value.

Comment: Please add the code to your question

Comment: if ( session.getEffectiveUserName()=="X")

Comment: Okay, I tried this:if (getComponent("computedField1").getValue() == "CN=Maris Puzaks/OU=LV/O=ExigenServices")
{
return 0;
}
else
{
return 1;
}
Still nothing. I don't see the error.

Comment: What is the outcome of getValue(). Maybe you should print that first, because if you have a submit button you should use getSubmittedValue()

Comment: But in SSJS and Java the == is not the same a String.equals(otherString)

Comment: when is this value checked? If the user enters the page or when a certain event has gone off? If it's the last please make sure that you refresh that specific button (either by a container that is partially refreshed, the button itself or a complete refresh ). 

Also be sure that the text you are comparing with is exactly the same (SSJS is case sensitive). If you want to be sure if the user you are comparing with is the same you could to something like this
"CN=user/OU=companydivision/O=companyname".toLowerCase().equals(session.getEffectiveUserName().toLowercase())

Comment: Also, return true or false (and not 0 or 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with:

```
getComponent("computedField1").getValue() == "User: x"
```

I didn't notice that I had "User" string attached to the computed field, so it returned false all the time. Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: The better, or more JAVAish way to do this is: "User: x".equals(getComponent("computedField1").getValue())